# conditional expression in while-loop does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, while-loop, expression, increment

I give conditional test to my while-loop but it doesn't seem working.
I think it's because of increment operator. but I couldn't find out why

```js
const nums = [3, 5, 15, 7, 5];
let n, i = 0;
while ((n = nums[i]) < 10, i++ < nums.length) {
  console.log(`Number less than 10: ${n}.`);
  };
```

expected [3, 5, 7, 5]
actual result [3, 5, 15, 7, 5]
I don't know why 15 came out.

I want to know why while-loop works like this.

**Update:**

This problem is from the book 'learning javascript 3rd'
and `,` comma operator doesn't work like I thought it should.

Comment: the comma operator doesn't do what you seem to think. Did you mean the logical "and" operator (`&&`) instead?

Comment: when i put && instead, it gives me only 3 and 5..

Comment: Because the while loop stops at 15 because you asked it to

Comment: very thank you you helps me a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while is shortcut when you get to 15 if you correct the , to an &&

The comma operator returns the result of the `i++ < nums.length`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

You really want to look into ES5/ES6 and filter

```js
let smallNums = [3, 5, 15, 7, 5].filter((n) => n<10)
console.log(smallNums)
```

Same without the ES6 arrow:

```js
let smallNums = [3, 5, 15, 7, 5].filter(function(n) { return n<10; })
console.log(smallNums)
```

Comment: !!The comma operator returns the result of the i++ < nums.length!!

Comment: just to clarify, `.filter` is in ES5. The arrow function is ES6 (but can easily be replaced by an ordinary anonymous function declaration if you have to support very old browsers like IE).

Comment: @RobinZigmond Updated

Answer (score 2):

Here. You should make a condition inside the while loop since if the condition is false then the whole loop will be terminated.

```js
const nums = [3, 5, 15, 7, 5];
let n, i = 0;
while (i < nums.length) {
  if ((n = nums[i++]) < 10) {
    console.log(`Number less than 10: ${n}.`);
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks very much! could you tell me how my code works??? i dont know why conditional expression doesn't catch the number more than 10

Comment: Note : you need to add a [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) into if statement to get the same of behaviour of while loop condition